# what [popViewControllerAnimated ]; do?

Tags: iphone

what  popViewControllerAnimated on the iphone SDK do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It closes the current view and returns to the parent view (the one that pushed the current view) with respect to the animation used when pushing it. For instance, when you tap on a contact in the contacts application, a view controller is pushed and displays that specific contact. When you close the view, `popViewController` is called that dismisses the current view and returns you back to the contact list view.

Comment: merc mehrdad jan :) 
mitoni in solae manam javab bedi ? daqiq motevajeh nashodam : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675113/best-idea-for-importing-text-to-each-navigationcontroller-view

Comment: That question is answered very well. What's unclear, exactly? BTW, these are fundamental concepts and you should use a book to make them pretty clear for you with a bunch of samples.

Answer (score 0):

From the [UINavigationController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popViewControllerAnimated:):

> This method removes the top view
>   controller from the stack and makes
>   the new top of the stack the active
>   view controller. If the view
>   controller at the top of the stack is
>   the root view controller, this method
>   does nothing. In other words, you
>   cannot pop the last item on the stack.
>
> In addition to displaying the view associated with the new view
>   controller at the top of the stack,
>   this method also updates the
>   navigation bar and tool bar
>   accordingly. In iPhone OS 3.0 and
>   later, the contents of the built-in
>   navigation toolbar are updated to
>   reflect the toolbar items of the new
>   view controller.

UINavigationController maintains a stack of UIViewControllers (shown in a schematic at the top of that class reference), each corresponding to a level of detail that you've stepped down into.  For example, you might be selecting locations, so you'd start with a table view controller that displays countries, then push a table view controller that displays states / provinces when the user selects a country.  When the user wants to step back a level in the navigation controller, it pops the current view controller off the stack and displays the previous one.  You can set whether this popping action is animated or not.

Typically this is handled for you by a "Back" button, but if you wanted to manually return the user to the previous level of the navigation controller, you'd use this method.

See also the [Navigation Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH103-SW1) section of the View Controller Programming Guide for iPhone OS.