# answer to my old question about navigation Controller !

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

i had questioned  here : [Best idea for importing text to each NavigationController View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675113/best-idea-for-importing-text-to-each-navigationcontroller-view)

the answer was this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PoemDetailsViewController *poemDetails = [[[PoemDetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PoemDetailsViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    poemDetails.poem = [poems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // assuming you have a single dimension array with poems and a single table group
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:poemDetails animated:YES];
}
```

now on on the PoemDetailsViewController i create an UIWebView and writing this code :

(i know this code shows only one of my HTML files)

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fal1" ofType:@"html"];
NSFileHandle *readHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:path];

NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: 
                            [readHandle readDataToEndOfFile] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

now i can't find any associating between  this code

```
poemDetails.poem = [poems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

to load poems on the AnotherViewController with each cell ?

i mean is every cells show their poem on the other view with Navigation Controller .

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use `NSString.stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:` ?

Comment: i have 495  cell so they had imported with plist property ! 

NSString *myfile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ghazal" ofType:@"plist"];
 ghazalList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myfile];


and :

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 return ghazalList.count;

}

and so on 
(why comment doesn't  the CODE tag ?!!)

Comment: @notnoop : sorry iam new to iphone SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line in question:

```
poemDetails.poem = [poems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

is simply passing information about the row (poem) that was selected to the new view controller.

Typically, the "poem" will be a custom class with relevant info about the poem such as its title and the name of its HTML file, but it could just be a string (if the title & HTML filename match).

For example, you would use it here:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:poem.filename ofType:@"html"];
```

Comment: so i used this :
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"poem" ofType:@"html"];

but does not work

Comment: That will (always) create the path string as "poem.html". You want the path to be dynamic (different for different poems), so you should use a variable as the path name like I suggest.